# How to add external lib to beanshell

Tags: java, google-api, beanshell

I have a beanshell code which use this librairies :

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics.Data.Ga.Get;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Accounts;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData.DataTable;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData.DataTable.Rows;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData.DataTable.Rows.C;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Profiles;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Webproperties;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;

...

Line 28 : JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
```

I download google-api-java-client jars, and add this at the beginning of my code :

```
addClassPath( "/Users/work/google-api-java-client/libs/" );
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I still have this error when running my code :

```
Evaluation Error: Sourced file: call_google_analytics.txt :
Typed variable declaration : Class: JsonFactory not found in namespace : 
at Line: 28 : in file: call_google_analytics.txt : JsonFactory
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in Beanshell when it comes to mapping all jars in a directory on adding items to the `Interpreter`'s classpath.

I have ran the following tests on the latest version you can depend on (without building the jar from [sources](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell)).
That would be `org.apache-extras.beanshell:bsh:2.0b6` from [2016](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache-extras.beanshell/bsh).

I have tried several options the [manual](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/classpath.html) provides on modifying the classpath, but none seem to work:

- import *;
- reloadClasses("");
- reloadClasses("com.google.*");

You can verify that your folder is added fine, but just not mapped, by looking at the console (`System.err`) output from the following beanshell script:

```
addClassPath("/test-project/lib/");
reloadClasses("com.google.*");
```

Console output:

```
Start ClassPath Mapping
Mapping: Directory C:\~\test-project\lib
End ClassPath Mapping
```

This shows the added directory is known, but none of the jar files in the directory were mapped. Otherwise they would be printed in this output.

I have traced this down to following piece of code in the `bsh.classpath.BshClassPath` class:

```
    synchronized void map( URL url ) 
        throws IOException 
    { 
        String name = url.getFile();
        File f = new File( name );

        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            classMapping( "Directory "+ f.toString() );
            map( traverseDirForClasses( f ), new DirClassSource(f) );
        } else if ( isArchiveFileName( name ) ) {
            classMapping("Archive: "+url );
            map( searchJarForClasses( url ), new JarClassSource(url) );
        }
```

We can see that on `if ( f.isDirectory()` it is only scanning for **classes** via `traverseDirForClasses( f )`. If you add a single Jar file then via `else if ( isArchiveFileName( name )`  it does scan the file for classes with `searchJarForClasses( url )`. Why it does not scan the directory for jar files and then classes is unknown to me.

As far as i'm concerned this is a bug, but i have not verified this with the latest `3.0` sources from github. If not a bug, then at least a missing feature. I have logged the [following issue](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/issues/646) on github.

The workaround is to add each jar separately, see the following beanshell script + output:

```
libPath = "/test-project/lib/";
addClassPath(libPath+"google-api-client-1.33.0.jar");
addClassPath(libPath+"google-http-client-1.41.0.jar");
addClassPath(libPath+"google-http-client-apache-v2-1.41.0.jar");
addClassPath(libPath+"google-http-client-gson-1.41.0.jar");

import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
return "Factory: " + JSON_FACTORY;
```

Evaluated beanshell script output:

```
Factory: com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory@1a407d53
```

If you don't want to manually maintain a list of jar files, you could also perhaps scan the directory yourself for jar files, and call `addClassPath` for every jar found in the script itself.

For example with a beanshell script like this:

```
libPath = "C:\\...\\test-project\\lib";
dir = new File(libPath);
filter = new java.io.FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");
    }
};

files = dir.listFiles(filter);
for(file: files) {
    addClassPath(file.toURL());
}
```